# show and Hide particular list elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code, i need to hide last list item

```
<div id="addUpdateFruit" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="list Box Design" id="listBox">
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="label" id="TypeLabel">Type:</li>
                        <li><select name="newTypeId" id="newTypeId">
                                <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
                        </select></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>   // Now want to hide only this
                    <ul>
                        <li class="label" id="FruitLabel">Fruit:</li>
                        <li><select name="newFruitId" id="newFruitId" class="required">
                                <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
                        </select></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>                                                               // Want to hide this
                    <ul>
                        <li class="label">Juice Type:</li>
                        <li><select name="Juice"  class="required" >   
                            <option value="1">MIlk Shake</option>
                            <option value="2">Normal</option>
                        </select></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

To do this, i used below codes

```
$('ul li:gt(2)').show();
```

and this

```
    var list = document.getElementById("listBox");    
    if (list.style.display == "none"){
        list.style.display = "block";
    }
```

Nothing seem working

How to hide or show Juice Type list item.Please help me on this

I want like this: where second list item is not shown

Type:                |______drop down___________|
Juice Type:          |______drop down___________|

Comment: `$('#listBox li:last').hide();`

Comment: rather than showing or hiding list items would it be easier to overwrite the whole list programmatically with some temp array ?

Comment: you can use `.eq()` `$('#listBox li").eq(-1).hide()`

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can amend your jQuery selector to use `:last`:

```
$('ul.listBox > li:last').hide();
```

Or preferably you could just use CSS:

```
ul.listBox > li:last-child { display: none; }
```

```css
ul.listBox > li:last-child { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="addUpdateFruit">
  <ul class="listBox" id="listBox">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li class="label" id="TypeLabel">Type:</li>
        <li>
          <select name="newTypeId" id="newTypeId">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li class="label" id="FruitLabel">Fruit:</li>
        <li>
          <select name="newFruitId" id="newFruitId" class="required">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li class="label">Juice Type:</li>
        <li>
          <select name="Juice" class="required">   
            <option value="1">MIlk Shake</option>
            <option value="2">Normal</option>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works!. But what if i want to hide 2nd list. that is fruit ?

Comment: In that case use `:eq(1)` instead of `:last`

Comment: Sorry, Actually i had used this $('#listBox ul li:gt(3)').hide(); to hide last list field instead of your answer. Given both the answer is not working. and what if i have class id with spaces inbetween refer latest edited question and how to hide second list item in particular?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It would help if you could update your question to give a clear statement about the HTML you have and the output you want to create

Comment: I want to hide only 2nd list item . I have edited question please refer

Comment: Then use `:eq(1)` as I mentioned before: https://jsfiddle.net/5jgnrhy9/ I noticed you changed the `class` of the `ul` in your edit so the selector is now `.list.Box`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

`$('ul li:nth-of-type(2)').hide();`

`$('ul li:last-of-type').hide();`